# What university should I put in resume if have not decided which one to attend yet?

Tags: resume

I will be joining a graduate program at a university in the upcoming fall. However, I am still deliberating on which university to join - I have multiple admits and they're all great schools. The final decision will likely take a long time (some of them start in winter semester).

Meanwhile, I need to start looking for internships for upcoming winter/summer.
Considering that the job market is quite bad at the moment, I need to start early or all the "good" positions will fill up.

To prove my eligibility for the internships,
I will need to put that I'll be pursuing a graduate degree in my resume.
Otherwise they won't consider my application.

Suppose I would join Univ X , then I'd write the following in the education section of my resume. I would put it as:

```
Univ X                                                 Expected: Month, 2025
(planned) Master of Science in Computer Science
```

But I don't know what Univ X is. What should I write?

Comment: You have to clarify with the company these details. We cannot have any idea what you should do when they request absurd information. The definition of CV refers to what already happened, or what is currently happening - definitely not what will be in the future. Sorry. Voted to close, because it is actually unanswerable.

Comment: This is very similar to the issue of needing to list an expected undergraduate degree, prior to actually graduating, when applying to graduate school, etc. If closed, I'd vote to re-open this question. (Although maybe it's more appropriate on SE Academia.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally you wouldn't put it in. But since this is required, put in the university you're most likely to be admitted to. If you're admitted to multiple and it's certain, put in any of them.

If you later pick another one, write an email to the HR clarifying you've gone to another college, with an updated CV.

Comment: As an academic worker, I'd say this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 10):

Me, personally, I wouldn't put anything on my CV that wasn't done. Now, you could discuss in your interview that you have offers from University X, Y and Z and you are still investigating the options.

But yeah - future plans (generally) aren't for a CV, keep it to what you've actually done and accomplished.

Comment: Indeed,  your résumé covers what have already achieved, your education, skills and accomplishments and not what you might/intend to do in the future. If you need to mention your ambitions and future plans, IMHO the place for that would be in the cover letter. For example something along the lines of  looking forward to joining the companies internship program to gain some real-world practical experience before continuing your formal education and pursuing a masters degree in computer science.

Comment: Many internship programs require the candidate to be a student. The CV needs to include something to this effect, you can't leave it out completely.

Comment: There's one circumstance where I would put something on the résumé that isn't done: When you're wrapping up a degree and applying for jobs that you would start after the degree is finished, it's fine to put "Master of Science, ABC University, May 2023 (expected)" or similar, but only in the case where you expect to have the degree before starting in the position.

Comment: -1: "I wouldn't put anything on my CV that wasn't done" -- this is in conflict with the OP's stated constraint that it's required on the resume for these internships.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could just leave the uni name out, and write "planned".

Comment: I favor calling the company and asking them this question, but I suspect this (or something similar( would in fact be their answer.